# What does a unicorn image on Github.com mean?

Tags: github, downtime

I went to view my repository on Github.com and was presented with a giant pink unicorn and a message saying:

> No server is currently available to service your request.

Does this mean something is wrong with my repository or account? Have I made in error in my repository?

If not, what's the issue?

[image: A Unicorn!]

Comment: What does *image* mean? Why not look at the [text below it](https://github.com/discussions/site/2314-outages)? "No server is currently available to service your request." What do you do about it? What the next line says: "Sorry about that. Please try refreshing and contact us if the problem persists."

Comment: It means someone at github has a sense of humor. An angry pink unicorn with a rainbow mane. They probably thought nobody would ever see it.

Comment: There are many Github app questions on SO @FactorMystic. While it seems trivial (or a joke), inexperienced users might assume it indicates there's a problem with their repository/account/etc. Instead of knowing it indicates there's a problem with Github as a whole.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Well, *it is* a problem with their repo. It just so happens it's a problem with everyone else's repo as well.

Comment: It's the 504 gateway time out for GitHub. To fix this error simply, reload the page.

Comment: @Amadan All these years later, what drove me to search this question was the fact that the first thing to come up in google when searching github unicorn is: "a simple tool for using a PowerShell downgrade attack and inject shellcode straight into memory. "

Obviously, what my brain first went into was a panic mode because it thought my repo was under attack or something. Someone in github has a really twisted sense of humour. I laughed, but for a moment I almost had a heart attack.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It means GitHub is down.  It means you can't use GitHub any more. See https://status.github.com/.

I guess you can bask in the unicorn's glory or something?  Other than that, you can do pretty much whatever you like.

One thing that also isn't down is https://developer.github.com/.

Comment: The status page says "Updated 11 days ago"

Comment: I don`t like the answer, the one with 'its the logo of their server' is more to the point. the unicorn project should get appreciation for the logo, not github

Answer (score 3):

This is the Unicorn logo, which is a way to host Rails projects.  Remember mongrel_rails?  It's like that but much, much faster.

When GitHub comes back online, you can see the Unicorn project [here](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn).

Answer (score 1):

It means that github is down for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Search for it in Google and check any of the link. Looks like that's the icon shown only when the site is down (or) the resource not found etc...

For example: check think link

https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn

Answer (score 0):

same thing happened to me, when i open it in pc it shows unicorn. In the same time i tried it in phone, it just running as usual. And a couple of minutes later github on pc back to normal again. So the solution for this just to wait, there is nothing we can do about it.